# Quarkus azure blob storage connection was closed

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, native, quarkus

Problem occurs on jar and native. During staging chunks i randomly get this error

> io.net.han.ssl.SslHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) [id: //redacted, L:///redacted - R://redacted.blob.core.windows.net///redacted] Last write attempt timed out; force-closing the connection.

> [com.azu.sto.blo.imp.Blo.stageBlock] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) <-- HTTP FAILED: Connection was closed

> (executor-thread-2) Got exception: : io.vertx.core.http.HttpClosedException: Connection was closed

Azure configuration class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Slf4j
public class AzureConfig {
    private static final FixedDelayOptions RETRY_OPTION = new FixedDelayOptions(3, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    private final AzureProperties properties;

    public AzureConfig(AzureProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient() {
        return createBuilder().buildClient().getBlobContainerClient(properties.containerName());
    }


    private BlobServiceClientBuilder createBuilder() {
        final String url = properties.url();
        final String baseUrl = url.endsWith("/") ? url : url + "/";

        final StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
                properties.accountName(), properties.accessKey());

        return new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(baseUrl + properties.accountName())
                .credential(credential)
                .httpClient(getHttpClient())
                .httpLogOptions(new HttpLogOptions()
                        .setLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS)
                        .setPrettyPrintBody(true))
                .retryOptions(new RetryOptions(RETRY_OPTION));
    }

    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        final HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions()
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3));
        return HttpClient.createDefault(clientOptions);
    }

}
```

Since i can't share whole code i provided pseudocode for class which is responsible for uploading chunks of file to cloud. We are not using azure async client.

```
initialize azure blob client
initialize azure block blob client

options = BlockBlobStageBlockOptions(chunkId, binaryData);
response = stage chunk with response(options, timeout=null, context.NONE)
...check response and provide appropriate information to client

if(is this last chunk)
    options = BlockBlobCommitBlockListOptions(chuIdList, binaryData);
    response = commit block list with response(options, timeout=null, context.NONE)
    ...check response and provide appropriate information to client
```

Dependencies:

- quarkus:2.16.0.Final
- camel-quarkus-azure-storage-blob:2.16.0

Configuration .yaml only contains simple azure configuration: container name, url, account-name, access-key

What i tried to solve this problem:

- increase connection timeout in azure client
- set camel.component.azure-storage-blob.timeout to higher Duration
- set quarkus.http.read-timeout to higher Duration
- set quarkus.rest-client.connect-timeout and read-timeout to higher Duration

We thought it might be connected to some weird behaviour in camel-quarkus-azure-storage-blob so we swapped it for testing purposes to com.azure.azure-storage-blob and problem didn't occur.

Right now we can't use com.azure.azure-storage-blob in native since we have a lot of problems during native build.

Could you please help me with this problem?